# Python. How to join two columns in one with variable number of spaces between

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, join

I have two columns/arrays filled with numbers in format 0.000 or -0.000. I would like to connect/join them together in one column, with 3 spaces between them.

I would like to achieve a result similar to:

```
connected = x.astype(str) + '   ' + y.astype(str)
```

or `numpy.vstack` or any other function connecting arrays/df columns etc (it's not important to use pandas).

The problem is, that depending on whether the number is negative or positive, I would like to join them with 2 spaces (when -0.000) or 3 (when 0.000).

For the columns in pandas df i wrote this function:

```
for x in df['column_a']:
    for y in df['column_b']:
        if y.startswith('-'):
            line = x + '  ' + y
            connected = np.append(connected, line)
        else:
            line = x + '   ' + y
            connected = np.append(connected, line)
```

which works, but is VERY SLOW.
Later, I need to put 3/2 spaces before this column **again**, based on the value of the first element.
I am sure there has to be a nicer solution, but have no idea how to find it.

Data:

```
a = numpy.random.randint(-5.000, 5.000, 500000)  
b = numpy.random.randint(-5.000, 5.000, 500000)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand whether these are actual numbers of strings, because I would think you can't call `startswith()` on an integer value. (And that you could just check for < 0). Also, you're going through your entirely dataframe N x N times, where N is the number of rows. Is that your intent?

Comment: So at this point it doesn't really matter if it's string or number, because I prepare them to be saves as .txt file anyway and the startswith was just my idea to get the result I want (which would also work with <0 with numbers, of course). I know the loops are an awful idea, I just didn't have a better one, but now I see, that could be done with one 'for' loop

Comment: I'm just saying if you're iterating over a dataframe per-row, it probably would be faster to just iterate once. `for row in df.itertuples(False):` and then deal with `row['column_a']` and `row['column_b']`.

Comment: @BenY I will for sure remember it for future, because I have a tendency to complicating my loops/iterations. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join them directly, but for the second column, where the value is less than 0, prefix some spaces, and otherwise, prefix more spaces.

```
>>> df['A'].astype(str) + np.where(df['B'] < 0,
...                                '  ' + df['B'].astype(str),
...                                '   ' + df['B'].astype(str))
0         -2   0
1         -2   3
2         -3  -1
3          4   4
4          0   3
 
499995     4   0
499996    -4  -2
499997    -4   2
499998     0  -4
499999     2  -4
Name: A, Length: 500000, dtype: object
```